# Invalid SQL statement for Text columns lookup

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, feature-class, text, update-query

I'm working in ArcGIS Pro and writing rows from a source file with Text data type field to another text field in a target file but it generates an error as such:

> An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT unique_id2, Col2, OID FROM
> fc2 WHERE unique_id2 is equal to 274162].

*note 274162 is the first value of unique_id1 which is also present in unique_id2. Below is my script:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["unique_id1","Col1"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        SQL_stat = "unique_id2 is equal to " +str(row[0])
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, ["unique_id2", "Col2"], SQL_stat) as cursor1: #Error
            for row1 in cursor1
```

My code works if the fields are Integer and not texts, but I need to work with text fields. Also a print statement of the SQL_stat prints out the WHERE clause as it ought to

Comment: Normally in SQL the strings appear between single quotes `'274162'`. Try that.

Comment: "is equal to" is a COBOL construct, not a SQL phrase. The equivalence operator for file geodatabase is "=" (except for NULL, which is "IS NULL"). For numerics, the comparison would be without quotes, for strings single-quotes are required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL statement (where\_clause) does not work for UpdateCursor syntax but same works for SearchCursor syntax](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404519/sql-statement-where-clause-does-not-work-for-updatecursor-syntax-but-same-work)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [AddFieldDelimiters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) and format to create the sql expression string:

```
SQL_stat = "{0} is equal to '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=fc2, field="unique_id2"), row[0])
```

Not sure how your data looks like, but you should probably think about using a dictionary instead of nesting cursors.
Something like:

```
datalookup = {k:v for k,v in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["unique_id1","Col1"])}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, ["unique_id2", "Col2"]) as cursor:
    if row[0] in datalookup:
        row[1] = datalookup[row[0]]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: There's a type mismatch issue at play here, so this won't work as-is for the OP, but which table has VARCHAR and which has INTEGER has never been stated.